# Take all cells in an Excel Worksheet in as String (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

Basically I'm creating a excel app that, when run, will prompt the user to point at the a specific excel file, and it will take the location in as a string, that works fine. What I am not sure how to do is choose a range in the active worksheet and take the value in each cell and combine them into 1 string.

This is my code so far:

```
Option Explicit

Sub locate_file()

Dim file As String
Dim sheet1_95 As String
Dim theRange As Range

'prompt user for location of other excel sheet'
file = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx")

'test input of location'
Workbooks("testing input file.xlsx").Sheets("location").Activate
Range("A1") = file

'activate the workbook and sheet'
Workbooks("95%.xlsx").Sheets("DT").Activate

'Testing retrieving cells as string'
Set theRange = Range("A2:A4")

'how do i retrieve values in this range and combine them into 1 string?'

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
'Testing retrieving cells as string'
Set theRange = Range("A2:A4")

'how do i retrieve values in this range and combine them into 1 string?'
Dim c as int, x as int
Dim strValue as string
c = therange.rows.count
strValue = vbnullstring
for x = 1 to c
strValue = strValue & theRange.cells(x,1).value
next x
```

Comment: I think you mean: .cells(x,1).value

Answer (score 3):

> What I am not sure how to do is choose a range in the active worksheet

By using the `Application.InputBox` function (as opposed to `VBA.InputBox`):

```
dim r as range
set r = application.inputbox("Select a range", Type:=8)
```

---

> and take the value in each cell and combine them into 1 string.

By looping through the cells:

```
dim c as range
dim s as string

for each c in r.cells
  s = s & c.value
next
```

Comment: If you have a large number of cells you have to process then use a variant instead. E.g., dim v as variant. v=application.inputbox("Select a range", Type:=8) 'Notice no set. Then just loop through the 2-d array.

Comment: @Jon49 That'd be an obscure equivalent of `v=application.inputbox("Select a range", Type:=8).Value`, and it'd fail in the user pressed Cancel. Also, as you say, if the number of cells is so big you start noticing the difference, you probaly don't want them all in memory *again*.

Comment: Didn't mean to criticize, I saw your answer was a good one but wanted to point out that looping through each cell is terribly slow. Also, a range object will fail if you use it without "on error" code. A variant will actually not fail, since it is a variant and will accept any type of object, I just tested it. It comes out typename(v) is type "Variant()" if there is a range selected and type "Boolean" if it is canceled. By far, good coding in VBA Excel is to use the variant method anytime you extract data from and process information from Excel using VBA.